# How do I drill through a metal screw in my cabinet doors?

Tags: woodworking, drill, cabinets, hardware, vanity

I'm in the process of adding hardware to my bathroom vanity and as I have gone to drill the holes in the doors, I am hitting metal. It's hard to see what it is, but I believe it's a screw or a piece of metal  on the joint where the wood comes together.

What do I need to do to get through it? OR can I just glue on the knobs and call it a day?![

enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qj9Ja.jpg)[image]

Comment: Whether or not you can drill through that screw depends on its function and the hole location. We can't say from what you've provided. Please post a link to a photo.

Comment: I doubt very much that you can drill through it. The steel  screw is so much harder than the wood your drill will be deflected into the wood.

Comment: I added a photo!

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't recommend the glue on idea.  I would relocate the knobs slightly.